# Dynamically added EditText do no match up to ones defined inside layout XML

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got two LinearLayouts side-by-side inside a TableLayout - one has 5 EditTexts added in sequence, and I have a button which adds an EditText to the other LinearLayout.

However, when adding the new ones dynamically, they don't match up to the pre-defined EditTexts in the first layout.

Here's my content.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.dcss.positiveday.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Positives" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView"
        android:text="Negatives" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:stretchColumns="*">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/postitiveItems"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint=":)" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint=":)" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint=":)" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint=":)" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText5"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint=":)" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/negativeItems"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText6"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint=":(" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:onClick="proceedClick"
                android:text="Proceed" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:onClick="addNew"
                android:text="New Negative" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

And here's my android code for dynamically adding them in:

```
package com.dcss.positiveday;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private LinearLayout _layout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        _layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.negativeItems);
    }

    public void addNew(View view) {
        EditText text = new EditText(MainActivity.this);

        text.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        text.setHint(":(");

        _layout.addView(text);
    }
}
```

Any items that are added are misaligned, and the offsets of the text don't match up. You can see that the EditTexts inside the layouts in both LinearLayouts match up.
Looking at my XML declarations from the other EditTexts, I don't seem to have any special layout positioning attached to it. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Why did you choose to craft your layout that way? The idea behind a `TableRow` is to put stuff on the same horizontal plane, the way tables have been done with computers since [VisiCalc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VisiCalc) in 1979. This layout looks like it should be an 9-row, 2-column table, yet that is not how you set up the layout XML.

Comment: I did use a GridLayout to position them both side-by-side, which looked correct in Android Studio's 'designer' but when running it on my phone they weren't 50% stacked equally. It took a lot of fiddling with the GridView to get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `EditText` views you are adding programmatically have no explicit style set, therefore they fall back to the device's default style, which, I presume, is the one from Android 4.x, while the `EditText` from your XML layout are styled are Android 5 Views, causing the Views to look differently.

I assume you are using AppCompat. Thus you have to apply the AppCompat style to your dynamically added `EditText`. You can do this by explicitly specifying the style attribute within the constructor:

```
EditText text = new EditText(MainActivity.this, null, R.attr.editTextStyle);
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that! I had a feeling something of that sorts was amiss - I was trying to play with manually changing the padding, but doing so caused me to reset the top/right/bottom values and couldn't figure out how to get the default style. Cheers

Comment: This works, but the(highlight) accent color is black not what i defined in the styles. Can you give any suggestion.